# XSL for-each gets only the first node value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Here is the foreach in my XSLT file:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/flights/flight/route[../plane/name/. ='Airbus 330']/routename"> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:attribute name="colspan" >2</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="style" >text-align:center</xsl:attribute><a><xsl:attribute name="href">map.php?a=<xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[../plane/name/. =$a]/from/latitude" />&amp;b=<xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[../plane/name/. =$a]/from/longitude" />&amp;c=<xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[../plane/name/. =$a]/to/latitude" />&amp;d=<xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[../plane/name/. =$a]/to/longitude" />&amp;e=<xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[../plane/name/. =$a]/routename" /></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[../plane/name/. ='Airbus 330']/routename"/></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

There are two routes that have an Airbus 330 plane, when running this for each, it creates the two table rows and links as desired, but using the first routename twice, instead of each routename. Why is this happening?

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<flights
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="flights.xsd">

<flight flightid="1">
    <flightno>EK98</flightno>
    <callsign>UAE98</callsign>
    <airline>Emirates Airline</airline>

    <plane planeid="1">
        <name>Airbus 330</name>
        <speed>567</speed>
        <registereddate>07-06-10</registereddate>
    </plane>

    <registration>3A6-EDJ</registration>
    <altitude height="feet">41000 feet</altitude>
    <speed ratio="mph">564 mph</speed>

    <route>
    <routename>Fiumicino-Dubai</routename>
    <course bearing="degrees">154 degrees</course>
    <distance type="miles">2697 miles</distance> 
    <duration>PT5H30M</duration>

        <from>
            <iatacode>FCO</iatacode>
            <airport>Fiumicino</airport>
            <country>Italy</country>
            <city>Rome</city>
            <latitude>41.8044</latitude>
            <longitude>12.2508</longitude>
        </from>

        <to>
            <iatacode>DXB</iatacode>
            <airport>Dubai Intl</airport>
            <country>UAE</country>
            <city>Dubai</city>
            <latitude>25.2528</latitude>
            <longitude>55.3644</longitude>
        </to>
    </route>

</flight>


<flight flightid="2">
    <flightno>BA283</flightno>
    <callsign>BAW283</callsign>
    <airline>British Airways</airline>

    <plane planeid="2">
        <name>Airbus 330</name>
            <speed>567</speed>
        <registereddate>06-12-97</registereddate>
    </plane>


    <registration>3A6-EDJ</registration>
    <altitude height="feet">41000 feet</altitude>
    <speed ratio="mph">564 mph</speed>

    <route>
        <routename>London-L.A</routename>
        <course bearing="degrees">154 degrees</course>
        <distance type="miles">5441 miles</distance> 
        <time>PT11H5M</time>
        <from>

            <iatacode>LHR</iatacode>
            <airport>Heathrow</airport>
            <country>England</country>
            <city>London</city>
            <latitude>51.4775</latitude>
            <longitude>0.4614</longitude>
        </from>

        <to>
            <iatacode>LAX</iatacode>
            <airport>Los Angeles Intl</airport>
            <country>USA</country>
            <city>L.A</city>
            <latitude>33.9471</latitude>
            <longitude>-118.4082</longitude>
        </to>
    </route>

</flight>

</flights>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace `<xsl:value-of select="/flights/flight/route[../plane/name/. ='Airbus 330']/routename"/></a>` with `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`. Inside the `for-each` the `routename` is the context node and you want to output that (and not start a new navigation through the document).

Comment: Thanks that worked, the link is now two different route names, but the parameters being passed are still the first set, can you show me how to iterate to the next set of parameters, I tried this but it didn't work: map.php?a=<xsl:value-of select="./from/latitude" />

Comment: As you process the `routename` as the context node, you need `<xsl:value-of select="../from/latidude"/>` which goes up to the parent `route` and then to the `from/latitude` descendant, or alternatively you could access the sibling `<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::from/latitude"/>`. As a third option you might change the `for-each` to process the `route` elements and then you could use `<xsl:value-of select="routename"/>` and `<xsl:value-of select="from/latitude"/>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked a treat I also understand a bit more of how this works. Thanks!!